# ArcObjects Java - Add-ins crashing ArcMap when starting editor

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arcobjects

I'm having a strange problem in my company. I've created several add-ins for ArcMap using ArcObjects for Java, and all of them do what they are supposed to.

The problem I'm facing occurs after going through these steps:

1. Install add-in (from inside ArcMap or by double-clicking on the .esriaddinx file).
2. Open ArcMap (if not already opened) and start a new MXD. Load some shapefiles if wanted.
3. Start editor. Do some editing (not required), and save them.
4. Save the new MXD file.
5. Close ArcMap.
6. Open ArcMap again, and load the previously saved MXD.
7. Start editor again -> CRASH. ArcMap closes with no error messages whatsoever.

Just to point out, not all ArcGIS installations here have this behaviour. The only ones are the LPS (Leica Photogrammetry Suite) machines with ERDAS Stereo Analyst extension (ArcGIS 10.2.1). I've executed the previous steps in my personal installation (no LPS, regular ArcGIS 10.2.2) and no problem occurs.

Is this problem related to some kind of problem in the LPS machines?

Or it might be my code not doing something that they expect it to do?

Relevant to say that many of my add-ins are not related in any way to the Editor extension, and if they are not installed the software runs fine (close, reopen and start editing). Looks like a problem in the MXD file that LPS machines are saving when my add-ins are installed. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but an information.

Seems like Java is not suitable enough for ArcObjects. I've migrated my entire code to C#, and those problems never occured. Apparently, it's some lack of ESRI support for Java libraries.

Recommendation for now is to forget about Java and ArcObjects. Libraries for VisualStudio are notably more up-to-date. Even the add-in configuration wizard has more options than the one for Eclipse/Java.